# Correct naming of joined collection in lookup mongoose

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

There is a problem with the naming of joined collection, which does not find it.

This is our collection schema. in which collection transaction is related to `ExpenseRecurring`

```js
const transaction = Schema(
  {
     ..
     ...,
    expenseRecurring: {
      type: SchemaTypes.ObjectId,
      ref: 'ExpenseRecurring',
      required: false,
    },
   ...
   ....
  {
    timestamps: true,
  }
);
```

But when we want to use the connection between them, we have no output. which is probably a naming problem

```
const aggregate = [
{
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'expenserecurrings',
    localField: 'expenseRecurring',
    foreignField: '_id',
    as: 'expenseRecurring',
  },
},
{
  $unwind: '$expenseRecurring',
},
{
  $match: { ...filter },
},

];
```

When I delete this lookup, all the data is returned.

I tested `expenserecurrings`, `expenseRecurrings`, `ExpenseRecurrings`, `ExpenseRecurring`

Comment: In `$lookup`, have you tried `from: 'ExpenseRecurring', localField: 'expenseRecurring', foreignField: '_id', as: 'expenseRecurring'`?

Comment: another thing to loook at is `expenseRecurring` and `_id` same type? that is either both object id or both string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check 2 things:

First, since you use `ref: 'ExpenseRecurring'`, it should match the name in the model creation, like this:

```
mongoose.model('ExpenseRecurring', recurringSchema)
```

They must be same.

Second, the from field in the lookup is the physical name of the collection.
For example, if you used `mongoose.model('ExpenseRecurring', recurringSchema)`, mongoose creates the collection as `expenserecurrings`. So the lookup must be like this:

```
            $lookup: {
                from: 'expenserecurrings',
                localField: 'expenseRecurring',
                foreignField: '_id',
                as: 'expenseRecurring',
            },
```